# Why would `sudo cp src dst` ignore no clobber rule in /etc?

Tags: bash, command-line, sudo, zsh

My global preferences, `alias cp='cp -iv'`, is ignored by `sudo` while using `zsh`.

I'm setting up a new system, and I'm trying out zsh for my user account. The root user still has bash. In `/etc` I have:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/zsh/zshenv
```

Both of these have the above alias, `alias cp='cp -iv'`.

In the user's directories, neither of these contains the commands in the `/etc` global configs.

```
~/.zshenv
/root/.bashrc
```

If I switch to the root user `su -` and try to clobber a file with copy, I get the correct prompt, `cp: overwrite 'fruits/apple.txt?'`. The same for the home user. However, if I `sudo` the copy command for the home user while in zsh, the file is overwritten! Using bash, I've not experienced this problem before, so I don't have a clue where else to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for `sudo` to work with your aliases, e.g. `sudo cp` ...

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

Comment: That's the answer--alias expansion of sudo was required in `/etc/zsh/zshenv`.